# How can I view the contents of tar.gz file without extracting from the command-line?

Tags: command-line

I want to see the contents (list of files and folders) of an archive, for example a  `tar.gz` file **without extracting** it.

Are there any methods for doing that?

Comment: Use `vim` to browse into the  files

Comment: [how-to-handle-compressed-files-with-vim](https://codeyarns.com/tech/2019-12-29-how-to-handle-compressed-files-with-vim.html)

Answer (score 448, accepted):

Run the below command in the terminal to see the contents of a tar.gz file without extracting it:

```
tar -tf filename.tar.gz
```

[image: screenshot of listing compressed tarball files in the terminal]

> -t, --list
> List the contents of an archive.  Arguments are optional.  When given, they specify the names of the members to list.

> -f, --file=ARCHIVE
> Use archive file or device ARCHIVE...

Comment: does all these examples to look inside compressed file works on other types of format too. like zip , rar , tar etc. ?

Comment: `tar -tvf xxx.tgz` this would also show detail properties of files.

Comment: pipe it to `tree` to see a tree view `tar -tf filename.tar.gz | tree `

Comment: For zip / rar use `unzip -l` / `unrar -l`

Comment: If you want to list until a specific **depth/level** only see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700306/listing-the-content-of-a-tar-file-or-a-directory-only-down-to-some-level).

Comment: I want to point out that `bsdtar` can `-tvf` zip files as well as extract them as if they were a stream.

Comment: @blockloop um, unless I'm a complete idiot, that's just going to list the contents of the current directory - not the tarfile. The manpage doesn't mention standard-input at all; and [this reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491235/12095) seems to match my findings. (Tree 1.7.0.)

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/list-the-contents-of-a-tar-or-targz-file/

Comment: I am so accustomed to using 7z for everything else that I continually forget that this method is far easier.

Comment: What if the tar is multi-volume?

Answer (score 183):

You can also use vim

```
vim filename.tar.gz
```

Comment: This is awesome. You can also see the contents of the files!

Comment: Or use Ex editor: `ex +%p foo.tar.gz`.

Comment: @Nico How do you use this to see the contents of a file within the tgz?

Comment: When you open de file with vim (`vim file.tar.gz`) it says "Select a file with cursor and press ENTER". You do just that, move the cursor over a file and press ENTER.

Comment: With huge archive you just have to be patient. It can be very long to load folder structure. :-)

Comment: Probably works with `vim`, doesn't work with `vi`.

Comment: How do you navigate through files? Enter selects a file, but how do I go back to the file list?

Comment: Tip for huge tarball: press ctrl+c to stop early and see a list of files without interaction.

Comment: @TimothyPulliam `:q` exits the current file and brings you back to the file list

Answer (score 58):

`less` can also open `gz`-compressed and uncompressed `tar` archives. It gives you a lovely `ls -l` style output too:

```
$ less ~/src/compiz_0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1.6.debian.tar.gz
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2012-09-21 11:41 debian/
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2012-08-09 13:32 debian/source/
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0              12 2012-08-09 13:32 debian/source/format
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0              25 2012-08-09 13:32 debian/libdecoration0-dev.docs
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0              25 2012-08-09 13:32 debian/compiz-dev.docs
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0             347 2012-08-09 13:32 debian/compiz-core.install
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0             125 2012-08-09 13:32 debian/libdecoration0-dev.install
...
```

And because it's `less`, you can scroll through it, search it, etc. However it fails miserably with other compression algorithms (in my experience).

Comment: Didn't work for me. Displayed as a binary file.

Comment: You sure you don't have an `alias` with special options for `less` that you're not showing here? I just tried that to see, but it didn't work. I don't have any aliases setup for `less`.

Comment: My `.bashrc` contains `[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"` which makes this work as described.

Comment: this worked for me, with a tarball compressed with the `xz` algorithm

Comment: Super useful, esp. as it also displays the mode bits and whether an entry is a link.

Answer (score 45):

You could use the z command: `zcat`, `zless`, `zgrep`.

To view a files content use:

```
zcat file.gz
```

To grep something use:

```
zgrep test file.gz
```

To check difference between files use:

```
zdiff file1.gz file2.gz
```

These are just a few example, there are many more.

Answer (score 15):

Well, that depends on the file. Most (de)compression programs have a flag that lists an archive's contents.

1. `tar`/`tar.gz`/`tgz`/`tar.xz`/`tar.bz2`/`tbz` files

   ```
   $ tar tf foo.tgz 
   dir1/
   dir1/subdir1/
   dir1/subdir1/file
   dir1/subdir2/
   dir1/subdir2/file
   dir2/
   ```
2. `zip` files

   ```
   $ zip -sf foo.zip 
   Archive contains:
     dir1/
     dir2/
     dir1/subdir1/
     dir1/subdir1/file
     dir1/subdir2/
     dir1/subdir2/file
   Total 6 entries (0 bytes)
   ```
3. `7zip` files

   ```
   $ 7z l foo.7z 

   7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
   p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

   Listing archive: foo.7z

   --
   Path = foo.7z
   Type = 7z
   Solid = -
   Blocks = 0
   Physical Size = 168
   Headers Size = 168

      Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
   ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
   2015-03-30 19:00:07 ....A            0            0  dir1/subdir1/file
   2015-03-30 19:00:07 ....A            0            0  dir1/subdir2/file
   2015-03-30 19:07:32 D....            0            0  dir2
   2015-03-30 19:00:07 D....            0            0  dir1/subdir2
   2015-03-30 19:00:07 D....            0            0  dir1/subdir1
   2015-03-30 19:00:06 D....            0            0  dir1
   ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                                        0            0  2 files, 4 folders
   ```
4. `rar` files

   ```
    $ rar v foo.rar 

   RAR 4.20   Copyright (c) 1993-2012 Alexander Roshal   9 Jun 2012
   Trial version             Type RAR -? for help

   Archive foo.rar

   Pathname/Comment
                     Size   Packed Ratio  Date   Time     Attr      CRC   Meth Ver
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    dir1/subdir1/file
                        0        8   0% 30-03-15 19:00 -rw-r--r-- 00000000 m3b 2.9
    dir1/subdir2/file
                        0        8   0% 30-03-15 19:00 -rw-r--r-- 00000000 m3b 2.9
    dir1/subdir1
                        0        0   0% 30-03-15 19:00 drwxr-xr-x 00000000 m0  2.0
    dir1/subdir2
                        0        0   0% 30-03-15 19:00 drwxr-xr-x 00000000 m0  2.0
    dir1
                        0        0   0% 30-03-15 19:00 drwxr-xr-x 00000000 m0  2.0
    dir2
                        0        0   0% 30-03-15 19:07 drwxr-xr-x 00000000 m0  2.0
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       6                0       16   0%
   ```

---

That's most of the more popular archive formats. With all this in mind, you could write a little script that uses the appropriate command depending on the extension of the file you give to it:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in "$@"
do
    printf "\n-----\nArchive '%s'\n-----\n" "$file"
    ## Get the file's extension
    ext=${file##*.}
    ## Special case for compressed tar files. They sometimes
    ## have extensions like tar.bz2 or tar.gz etc.
    [[ "$(basename "$file" ."$ext")" =~ \.tar$ ]] && ext="tgz"

    case $ext in
        7z)
            type 7z >/dev/null 2>&1 && 7z l "$file" || 
            echo "ERROR: no 7z program installed"
            ;;
        tar|tbz|tgz)
            type tar >/dev/null 2>&1 && tar tf "$file"|| 
            echo "ERROR: no tar program installed"
            ;;
        rar)
            type rar >/dev/null 2>&1 && rar v "$file"|| 
            echo "ERROR: no rar program installed"
            ;;
        zip)
            type zip >/dev/null 2>&1 && zip -sf "$file"|| 
            echo "ERROR: no zip program installed"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown extension: '$ext', skipping..."
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Save that script in your `PATH` and make it executable. You can then list the contents of any archive:

```
$ list_archive.sh foo.rar foo.tar.bz foo.tar.gz foo.tbz foo.zip

-----
Archive 'foo.rar'
-----

RAR 4.20   Copyright (c) 1993-2012 Alexander Roshal   9 Jun 2012
Trial version             Type RAR -? for help

Archive foo.rar

Pathname/Comment
                  Size   Packed Ratio  Date   Time     Attr      CRC   Meth Ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 dir1/subdir1/file
                     0        8   0% 30-03-15 19:00 -rw-r--r-- 00000000 m3b 2.9
 dir1/file
                     0        8   0% 30-03-15 19:29 -rw-r--r-- 00000000 m3b 2.9
 dir1/subdir1
                     0        0   0% 30-03-15 19:00 drwxr-xr-x 00000000 m0  2.0
 dir1
                     0        0   0% 30-03-15 19:29 drwxr-xr-x 00000000 m0  2.0
 dir2
                     0        0   0% 30-03-15 19:07 drwxr-xr-x 00000000 m0  2.0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    5                0       16   0%


-----
Archive 'foo.tar.bz'
-----
dir1/
dir1/subdir1/
dir1/subdir1/file
dir1/file
dir2/

-----
Archive 'foo.tar.gz'
-----
dir1/
dir1/subdir1/
dir1/subdir1/file
dir1/file
dir2/

-----
Archive 'foo.tbz'
-----
dir1/
dir1/subdir1/
dir1/subdir1/file
dir1/file
dir2/

-----
Archive 'foo.zip'
-----
Archive contains:
  dir1/
  dir1/subdir1/
  dir1/subdir1/file
  dir1/file
  dir2/
Total 5 entries (0 bytes)
```

---

And since someone mentioned that lesser editor, naturally, emacs can also do this:

[image: emacs showing an archive's contents]

Answer (score 9):

Why not use `vim` to browse your archive and open files (at least text-like files):

```
vim archive.tar.gz
```

[image]

Press the arrow keys to scroll and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a file.

Answer (score 9):

`tar`'s `-t` flag will list contents for you. Add that to your other flags (so `-tvfz` for a `tar.gz`, `-tvfj` for a `tar.bz2`, etc) and you can browse without extracting. From there you can extract single files quite easily

```
tar -xvfz mybackup.tar.gz path/to/file
```

The big problem with `tar` is [remembering all the *other flags*](https://xkcd.com/1168/). So I usually rely on `7z` (of the `p7zip-full` package) to do all my archiving. I won't claim it is entirely better but it supports almost everything (without having to specify compression type) and the arguments are logical.

```
7z l archive.ext
7z e archive.ext path/to/file
```

It's certainly less capable, but you don't *need* the man page to use it.

There's also Midnight Commander (`mc`). This is an all-around badass for quasi-graphical terminal-based file management and with some light testing it just let you browse into both `.tar.gz` and `.7z` archives. I'm not sure how many others it supports.

Comment: t-ar used to be and the name indeed stands for **tape** archiver, that screams sequential and is in many cases a PIA. [Especially as the inevitable double tar + gz](https://superuser.com/questions/252065/gzip-without-tar-why-are-they-used-together) this is just cruel. Also moving to 7zip now.

Answer (score 6):

`lesspipe` is a shell script installed by default as part of the `less` package that can list the contents of a `tar.gz` archive, as well as a range of other common archive file formats.

```
$ lesspipe example.tar.gz
drwxrwxr-x ubuntu/ubuntu     0 2018-11-16 05:32 example/
-rw-rw-r-- ubuntu/ubuntu     7 2018-11-16 05:32 example/ask.txt
-rw-rw-r-- ubuntu/ubuntu     7 2018-11-16 05:32 example/ubuntu.txt
```

It is called by the `less` command ([see Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392885/how-can-i-view-the-contents-of-tar-gz-file-without-extracting-from-the-command-l/393032#393032)) as an input preprocessor if the `$LESSOPEN` environment variable is set appropriately.

If feeling adventurous, take a peak at `vi /usr/bin/lesspipe` to see what commands it uses. For files matching the `tar.gz` extension, we can see that it uses `tar tzvf` under the hood along with the `--force-local` option to disable an obscure feature of `tar` that would otherwise confuse [colons in the filename](https://superuser.com/questions/287233/tar-command-to-extract-archive-with-colon-in-the-name/505174#505174) with a command to use a remote tape drive:

```
*.tar.gz|*.tgz|*.tar.z|*.tar.dz)
        tar tzvf "$1" --force-local
```

Note that because it's primarily designed as a preprocessor for `less`, it won't output anything if it doesn't recognise the file type. I noticed that some `.tar.gz` files I downloaded wouldn't work because they didn't actually use gzip compression despite the filename.

Answer (score 5):

Midnight Commander (`mc`) also has a good compressed file viewer, although I consider this a bit of cheating since mc *is* a file manager, albeit a text-based one.

Also, if all you want is to see what's inside compressed archives, you could learn the "view" command for each compressor. `tar tzvf` will show you the contents of a tar file, `unzip -l` will do it for a zip file, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Using 
`view filename.tar.gz` 
will also work. much in the same way vim does, but without write permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view the contents of a specific file within an archive without extracting the archive or writing to disk in any way, use the -O (capital o) flag to write to stdout instead of a file.

```
tar -Oxvf gerald.tar.gz /path/to/sandra.txt | less
```

Make sure the O comes before the f or it will try to parse the O as a filename.