# Find and search inside all compressed files

Tags: search, archive

I'd like to scan my hard drive for all compressed file collections like zip, gzip, bzip, and others and have the content of those searched for certain file types (such as images).  Anti-virus' do it, so I believe there should be a way.

Comment: @Rinzwind that will search within the files of the archive, not within the list of files. It will find files containing `foo` but not `foo.png`.

Comment: This may be helpful to check for a Zip Bomb! +1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to list the contents of the archive and look for files of the relevant extension. For example, with a `zip` file:

```
$ zip -sf foo.zip | grep -iE '\.png$|\.jpg$'
  file1.jpg
  file1.png
  file2.jpg
  file2.png
```

The `-sf` option tells `zip` to list the files contained in an archive. Then, the `grep` will look for a `.png` or `.jpg` that are at the end of the line (`$`). The `-E` enables extended regular expressions, so we can use `|` as OR and the `-i` makes the matching case insensitive.

However, each archive tool has a different command to list the contents. [I've written a script](https://askubuntu.com/a/603200/85695) that can deal with most of the more popular ones. If you save that script as `list_compressed.sh`, you could then run:

```
list_compressed.sh | grep -iE '\.png$|\.jpg$|\.jpeg$|\.gif$|\.tif$|\.tiff$'
```

That would show you the most common image types. Note that this approach assumes that the file type can be determined by the file's extension. It will not find image files that don't have an extension and it will not recognize files with the wrong extension. There is no way to deal with that without actually extracting the files from the archive and running `file` on each of them.

---

If you want to find *all* archives that contain image files on your hard drive, combine the above with `find`:

```
find / -name '*.gz' -o -name '*.tgz' -o -name '*.zip' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' arch; do    
        list_compressed.sh "$arch" | 
            grep -qiE '\.png$|\.jpg$|\.jpeg$|\.gif$|\.tif$|\.tiff$' &&
                echo "$arch contains image(s)"
    done
```

The find command will search for all `.gz`, `.tgz` or `.zip` files (you can add as many extensions as you like), those are then passed through my script. The `-q` suppresses grep's normal output, nothing will be printed. The `&& echo` will print the archive's name only if the `grep` was successful.

Comment: According to my original question I'd like to "scan my hard drive for all compressed file collections, like zip, that contain images".  You've helped for looking into the archives themselves, but I just want to identify which archives contain images.

Comment: @6ftDan sorry, I hadn't seen the original. Please feel free to roll back or re-edit any edit that changes the meaning of your post. See updated answer for how to search the entire file system.

Comment: Great, but since you're grepping case-insensitively maybe you want to also search case-insensitively?

Comment: @kos hmm, that's easy enough to do just change `-name` to `-iname`. However, there's little point to it, many compression programs (gzip, for example) need the specific extension. `GZ` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Not as advanced as terdon, but this will do:

Save the following code, in a folder where all your code resides in, as `finda.sh`, or any other name as you like:

```
for file in *.*; do
    if ( 7z l -slt "$file"> /tmp/$file.log); then
       echo $file:; cat /tmp/$file.log | grep -iE 'Path*'> $file.log && cat $file.log
    fi
done
```

Then in a dir were all of your archives are in, run it and this is the output:

```
./finda.sh 
one.7z:
Path = one/abradabra.png
Path = one/birb.png
three.rar:
Path = three/blah.png
Path = three/qwa0g.jpg
two.zip:
Path = two/whut.png
```

Comment: According to my original question I'd like to "scan my hard drive for all compressed file collections, like zip, that contain images".  You've helped for looking into the archives themselves, but I just want to identify which archives contain images.

Comment: @6ftDan That, I think is possible, but may take a while. In the mean time, I added some improvements to my script, whit the help of terdon.

Comment: Note that `*.*` will only match files with an extension. Also, this will list _all_ files in _all_ archives, you're not testing for any file type.