# Search for a file inside all of tar.gz

Tags: find, tar, automation

i have a lot's of tar.gz files in random place 
and i want to look for a file inside all of tar.gz file

for example :

```
/root/a.tar.gz
/home/backup-2016.tar.gz
/home2/user/files/2015/abc.tar.gz
```

i am looking for **file** or **folder** inside of them

Comment: You can find answer to your question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/392885/how-can-i-view-the-contents-of-tar-gz-file-without-extracting-from-the-command-l

Comment: @Ejaz please read my question again , i want to "find all tar.gz" file then looking inside all of them !

Comment: You want to process all *.tar.gz files in your computer and list those containing files/directories whose names match your search pattern?

Comment: I think he's trying to search for a file with a given filename within all the tar.gz files on his computer.  A combination of commands in my opinion, and best done with a custom script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this (rather long) one-liner, replacing `PATTERN` with your search pattern (case insensitive unless you remove the `-i` option after `grep`):

```bsh
find / -iname "*.tar.gz" -exec bash -c 'result=$(set -o pipefail ; echo "{}" ; tar -tf {} | grep -i "PATTERN" | sed "s/^/    /") ; test $? -eq 0 && printf "$result\n"' \;
```

If you don't want to search your whole computer but just a specific directory (recursively), you may specify that as first argument after `find` instead of the `/`. The `.tar.gz` suffix for archives to process is case insensitive as well unless you replace the `-iname` after `find` with `name`.

The output might look somehow like this (searching in `/usr/share/doc` for the pattern `default`):

```
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/failed_tests-hotspot.tar.gz
    test/langtools/JTwork/tools/javac/lambda/methodReferenceExecution/MethodReferenceTestInnerDefault.jtr
    test/langtools/JTwork/tools/javac/lambda/methodReferenceExecution/MethodReferenceTestSuperDefault.jtr
    test/langtools/JTwork/tools/javac/lambda/methodReferenceExecution/MethodReferenceTestVarArgsSuperDefault.jtr
    test/langtools/JTwork/tools/javac/lambdaShapes/org/openjdk/tests/vm/DefaultMethodsTest.jtr
/usr/share/doc/apg/php.tar.gz
    ./themes/default.php
```

You see the archive path in one line followed by all content entries matching the pattern, each in a separate line indented by 4 spaces.

---

This can be also put in a script (e.g. `archive-search`, don't forget to make it executable with `chmod +x FILENAME`):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Usage:   archive-search PATTERN DIRECTORY

find "$2" -iname "*.tar.gz" -exec bash -c '
        result=$(
                set -o pipefail
                echo "{}"
                tar -tf {} | grep -i "$0" | sed "s/^/    /"
        )
        test $? -eq 0 && printf "$result\n"
' "$1" \;
```

or in a Bash function (e.g. `archive-search`, append to your `~/.bashrc` if you want to have it available in every new Bash session):

```bsh
archive-search () {
    # Usage:   archive-search PATTERN DIRECTORY

    find "$2" -iname "*.tar.gz" -exec bash -c '
            result=$(
                    set -o pipefail
                    echo "{}"
                    tar -tf {} | grep -i "$0" | sed "s/^/    /"
            )
            test $? -eq 0 && printf "$result\n"
    ' "$1" \;
}
```

Both the script and the function take search pattern and directory as command-line arguments, like this:

```
archive-search "default" /usr/share/doc
```