# See contents of .tar.gz while it is being created

Tags: tar

I am making a very large tar.gz file and I want to see how much is already in the file while it currently being created. To measure its progress. Just want to know the amount of files and maybe also the names.

Is that possible and most important safely by doing one of the various methods described in [How can I view the contents of tar.gz file without extracting from the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392885/how-can-i-view-the-contents-of-tar-gz-file-without-extracting-from-the-command-l?noredirect=1&lq=1) ?

I am also creating this archive by a complex command that lists all the file locations and pipe this to tar. Like so

```
complex command | tar czf archive.tag.gz -C /root/folder/ . -T -
```

Comment: Replace tar czf by tar czvf? (Not sure of order. I always use zcvf)

Comment: Tar process is already running, but that would have been a better idea.

Comment: O you can do tar ztvf ‹file› to an incomplete tar file. It will show whatever it can and then error out